# How to slow down the speed of zooming functionality using Javascript or D3 JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

How to slow down the speed of zooming functionality using Javascript or D3 JS. What I have tried is below. I used d3 js for this.

```js
var zoom = d3.behavior.zoom().on('zoom.zoom', function() {
  root.attr('transform', 'translate(' + d3.event.translate + ')' + 'scale(' + d3.event.scale + ')');
})

var svg = d3.select('svg').call(zoom);
```

This code is perfect for zooming but when it zooms it is pretty fast and looks odd. What to do to slow down the speed when scroll bar is raised for zooming.

Comment: What affects the speed of the transformation and translation are the parameters:

 - `d3.event.translate`
 - `d3.event.scale`

The solution is to decrease these so that the effect is less pronounced.

Try dividing by two.

Comment: That didnt work for me. That is the reason I have posted this for alternate answer which solves. So dont mark unnecessarily as duplicate. That answer affects the transition and does not zoom evenly

Comment: have a look @ https://jsfiddle.net/839bcnmy/7/ . It takes a bit of math but you need to take the transform.k and calculate the difference with the previous one. Then you can decide to divide or multiply which either increases or decreases the change.

Answer (score 0):

Add `transition-duration`

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  transition-duration: 2s;

}

div:hover {
   transform:translate(10px) scale(0.5);
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```